# Defining rails routes using resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just started my journey with ruby on rails
not sure but if it's possible to rewrite following route with 'resources':

```
get '/comments/:object_type/:object_id', to: 'comments#get_all'
```

where comments_controller handles request:

```
  def get_all
    @object_type=params[:object_type]
    @object_id=params[:object_id]
    @comments = Comment.get_all(@object_type, @object_id)
    ...(irrelevant code)
  end

  def self.get_all(object_type, object_id)

    case object_type
    when 'task'
      Comment.select('comments.*, profiles.first_name, profiles.last_name, profiles.avatar')
          .joins(user: :profile)
          .where(task_id:object_id)
          .order(created_at: :desc)
   # TODO when 'project' and other types
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end
```

it's working just fine however it's a bit ugly and project that I've started maintain is using 'resources' only as far

Comment: I’m not sure you’re correct in assuming that your irrelevant code is irrelevant. Is there a difference between `/comments/foo/1` and `/comments/bar/1` ? This is a question of how you’re mapping your comments to RESTful resources. The name “object” is super vague so it’s hard to know what’s happening and of the resources can be better structured. If you don’t want to share the code - or even if you do - a quick description of the object relation model would help too.

Comment: ok, updated with more code
:object_type is just different type of commented hmm..well objects :) like task, project,...and many more, it's used to distinguish proper id column in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly following the RESTful resources pattern, you’d have quite different urls. It can be a good pattern to follow and certainly a pattern worth understanding if you’re looking to improve your rails.

I’ll assume the ‘commentable’ objects are models in their own right, so you have a models/project.rb and models/task.rb file.

The URLs for this functionality, if you consider Project, Task and Comment as RESTful resources, would be:

```
/tasks/:task_id/comments
/tasks/:task_id/comments/:comment_id
/projects/:task_id/comments
/projects/:task_id/comments/:comment_id
```

So, to answer your question: no; you cannot build the specific routes you want using resources. The RESTful routes is a very opinionated and prescriptive approach.

They are decent opinions, and you’ll find that rails has opinions about everything. If you follow along, you’ll get a lot of value from rails. If you decide you want to go your own way; you might want to reconsider and find a less opinioned framework.

In your routes.rb try the following

```
resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :show]
end

resources :projects, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

And then run `rake routes` to see all of the URLs in your app and which controllers they point to.

You’ll need to change how your controller works when you use this pattern.

There are reasons to not use RESTful routes pattern. Maybe your legacy app has those URLs already in place and you don’t want to break old paths. But if you’re new and adding these non-resource based routes you might be breaking from the existing design pattern in use in the app.

This doesn’t answer how to rewrite your controller, or that you’ll likely want to use a “commentable” concern to allow your Projects, Tasks etc to share code around how to take comments. Those would be different questions and you should try it yourself first.

But I hope this helps you understand the routes and resources a bit better. And welcome to rails.

Also see https://medium.com/@atingenkay/restful-routes-what-are-they-8fe221521bb